# Giving new div id support to jquery function (2 tabs blocks example)?

Tags: jquery

Here is jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });

});
```

OK, following HTML using upper jquery (and CSS) creates popular tabs (two tabs blockS actually)..

HTML

```
//first block
    <div>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">2</a></li>
    </ul>
     <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">Content 1</div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">Content 2</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>Something images in between</div>
  
//second block  
    <div>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">4</a></li>
    </ul>
     <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">Content 3</div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">Content 4</div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

When page loads

- only content of first block (first tab) is shown (while second block first tab is closed),
- clicking tabs in second block closes/affects content of first block, of course.

  How can I make it for both blocks (as well as first tabs) to be shown, as well for blocks to function as separate ids for example?

Thanx!

Comment: You mean: Content 1 and Content 3 must be visible on page load, and working with first block shouldn't affect second block?

Comment: @Dart Yeah Dart!!! This code was intended for use with only just one block of course, but I wish it could work with a few at once if possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/54fDF/

HTML

```
//first block
    <div>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">2</a></li>
    </ul>
     <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">Content 1</div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">Content 2</div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div>Something images in between</div>

//second block  
    <div>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">4</a></li>
    </ul>
     <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">Content 3</div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">Content 4</div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_container").find("div:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        var contId = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        var parent = $(contId).parent();
        parent.find('.tab_content').hide();
        $(contId).fadeIn();
    });
});
```